# How to highlight specific portion within DateTimePicker Programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datetimepicker

I have a **DateTimePicker control (custom format)** onto my windows forms application that I am generating **programmatically**.

To highlight a specific portion / part (e.g. Hour) within it, I have to manually click on it. It is required that I be able to perform this highlighting on a specific part of the DateTimePicker programmatically (and not by manual click).

I have tried using the events, methods and other properties of the DateTimePicker control. I also have searched and re-searched the internet and came across no direction.

Here is a screenshot for illustration:

[image]

Over here, onto the cell of the DataGridView, lies my custom format DateTimePicker.

Comment: DateTimePicker has no support for that.  Programmers desperately enough have used SendKeys.Send to work around that.  You have to be pretty desperate.

Comment: Hi Hans, SendKeys can be utilized to open up the default formatted DateTimePicker. However the case is a little bit different here.

Comment: Why is it necessary to highlight that bit programmatically?  Why can't you just let the user select which part they're going to change?  Just wondering.  Maybe you could replace the spinbox with another control that does allow programmatic selection?

Comment: Hi Ian, I agree but it is the requirement of my client. Just a correction, it is not a spinbox, it is a datetimepicker with up-down control shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally discovered a solution. I would want to share it so that people having similar issues in future may benefit from it.

The cause of DateTimePicker (DTP) to loose it's usual behavior was because:

- **It was being generated programatically and "Added" as a control to the GridView (instead of form)**

Hence the regular methods like "Select()" and "Focus()" were failing to be applied.

I simply placed the DTP control onto the form and made invisible. Then whenever I needed to edit a cell, the control overlay-ed the cell and focus was shifted to it. Like normal DTP control, now it automatically highlighted the first part i.e. hour in my case.

This is the essence of the solution. Rest is handling of unexpected occurrences. I cannot share code due to it being a product of some client.